# Can I run a DLL in a separate thread?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, dll

I have a program I'm writing in vb.net that has ballooned into the most complicated thing I've ever written.  Because of some complex math and image rendering that's happening constantly I've been delving into multithreading for the first time to improve overall performance.  Things have honestly been running really smoothly, but we've just added more functionality that's causing me some trouble.

The new functionality comes from a pair of DLLs that are each processing a video stream from a USB camera and looking for moving objects.  When I start my program I initiate the DLLs and they start viewing the cameras and processing the videos.  I then periodically ping them to see if they have detected anything.  This is how I start and stop them:

```
Declare Function StartLeftCameraDetection Lib "DetectorLibLeft.dll" Alias "StartCameraDetection" () As Integer
Declare Function StopLeftCameraDetection Lib "DetectorLibLeft.dll" Alias "StopCameraDetection" () As Integer
```

When I need to check if they've found any objects I use several functions like this:

```
Declare Function LeftDetectedObjectLeft Lib "DetectorLibLeft.dll" Alias "DetectedObjectLeft" () As Integer
```

All of that works really well.  The problem is, I've started to notice some significant lag in my UI and I'm thinking it may be coming from the DLLs.  Forgive my ignorance on this, but as I said I'm new to using multiple threads (and incorporating DLLs too if I'm honest).  It seems to me that when I start a DLL it running it's background tasks on my main thread and just waiting for me to ping it for information.  Is that the case?  If so, is it possible to have the DLL running on a sperate thread so it doesn't affect my UI?

I've tried a few different things but I can't seem to address the lag.  I moved the code that pings the DLL and processes whatever information it gets into a sperate thread, but that hasn't made any difference.  I also tried calling StartLeftCameraDetection from a separate thread but that didn't seem to help either.  Again, I'm guessing that's because the real culprit is the DLL itself running these constant background tasks on my main thread no what thread I actually call it's functions from.

Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to offer!

Comment: "The DLL" isn't some separate entity.  It's part of your process.  So yes, you can run anything you want from a dll in a separate thread, just as you can run anything you want from your own code in a separate thread.

Comment: Note that part of your problem is likely to be making sure that your UI isn't blocking while the processing is happening.  That's related to running CPU-bound code on a separate thread, but it's not exactly the same problem.  `Async` and `Await` will help with this.

Comment: Once you introduce `Async` and `Await`, your code is potentially re-entrant, so you'll need to make sure it behaves correctly.

Comment: One other thing... if you're operating through `Declare Function`, I wouldn't expect the exports to be doing UI-type things.  They might do their own threading, but that's not going to be negatively affected by you pushing them off into a worker thread.  As I noted before, the problem is probably that you still have something set up that's blocking the UI thread waiting for processing to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot to grok when it comes to threading, but I'll try to write a concise summary that hits the high points with enough details to cover what you need to know.

Multi-threaded synchronization is hard, so you should try to avoid it as much as possible.  That doesn't mean avoiding multi-threading at all, it just means avoiding doing much more than sending a self-contained task off to a thread to run to completion and getting the results back when it's done.

Recognizing that multi-threaded synchronization is hard, it's even worse when it involves UI elements.  So in .NET, the design is that any access to UI elements will only occur through one thread, typically referred to as the UI thread.  If you are not explicitly writing multi-threaded code, then all of your code runs on the UI thread.  And, while your code is running, the UI is blocked.

This also extends to external routines that you run through `Declare Function`.  It's not really accurate to say that they are doing anything with "background tasks on the main thread", if they are doing anything with "background tasks" they are almost certainly implementing their own threading.  More likely, they aren't doing any task breakdown at all, and all of their work is being done on whichever thread you use to call them---the UI thread if you're not doing anything else.

If the work being done in these routines is CPU-bound, then it would definitely make sense to push it off onto a worker thread.  Based on your comments on what you already tried:

> I moved the code that pings the DLL and processes whatever information it gets into a sperate thread, but that hasn't made any difference. I also tried calling StartLeftCameraDetection from a separate thread but that didn't seem to help either.

I think the most likely problem is that you're blocking in the UI thread waiting for a result from the background thread.

The best way to avoid this depends on exactly what the routines are doing and how they produce results.  If they do some sort of extended process and return everything in function results, then I would suggest that using `Await` would work well.  This will basically return control to the UI until the operation finishes, then resume whatever the rest of the calling routine was going to do.

Note that if you do this, the user will have full interaction with the UI, and you should react accordingly.  You might need to disable some (or all) operations until it's done.

There are a lot of resources on `Async` and `Await`.  I'd particularly recommend reading Stephen Cleary's blog articles to get a better understanding of how they work and potential pitfalls that you might encounter.

Comment: Thanks so much.  That makes a lot of sense.  I also see now that my comment about "background tasks on the main thread" doesn't make a lot of sense.  What I should have said is I believe the DLL is running a continuous loop once I call StartLeftCameraDetection.  The way the image processing works it needs to check each frame of video against the last and compare them so that is constantly happening in the DLL once I start it.  I then ping it to see if it has any information.  I can see that my code which pings the DLL and processes anything that comes back is running really fast (1-2ms).

Comment: It seems like just the DLL running is slowing my UI down a lot.  I'll try to show a form and it might take a few seconds or I pop up a message box and get the same long delay.  I was really hoping there was a way to just set the DLL up in it's own thread and let it run without affecting my UI.  I should also note the I didn't write the DLL.  It was written by another developer.  I've reached out to him for some insight as well.

Comment: @KipPolley Performance might depend on your computer resources, though I think most PCs these days have at least two cores.

Comment: I suppose it might be possible for the DLL routine to somehow capture the window procedure for your program, if that were the case and it were to block for operations taking a macroscopic amount of time, then it could interfere with UI performance.  I'd find that surprising for a DLL routine.

Comment: ok.  I really appreciate your input on this.  I'm going to keep chasing this down but I feel like I at least have a better understanding of what's happening.  Thanks!